# I can't connect to mysql server in maven using Intelij

Tags: mysql, maven

I have the problem, when i try to connect with my database i get the error:

> [MySQL] Can't connect to the mysql server: Could not create connection
>   to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

I was able to connect with the "Database" tab in Intelij so probably there isn't anything wrong with the database or it is a bug but i can't fix it. I would really appreciate your help. I thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
package Code;

import Database.MySQLManager;

public class ModuleSearcher {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MySQLManager mySQLManager = new 
MySQLManager("localhost","username","password","login",3306);
    mySQLManager.connect();


}

}
```

The other one:

```
package Database;

import java.sql.*;

public class MySQLManager {

private String hostname, username, password, database;
private int port;

private Connection con;

public MySQLManager( String hostname, String username, String password, 
String database, int port ) {
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.database = database;
    this.port = port;
}

//<editor-fold desc="Connect">
public void connect( ) {
    try {
        this.con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + 
":" + port + "/" + database +
                "?autoReconnect=" + true, username, password );

        if ( !con.isClosed( ) && con != null ) {
            System.out.println( "[MySQL] Sucessfully connected." );
        }

    } catch ( SQLException err ) {
        System.err.println( "[MySQL] Can't connect to the mysql server: " + 
err.getMessage( ) );
    }
}
//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="Close">
public void close( ) {
    try {
        if ( !con.isClosed( ) && con != null ) {
            con.close( );
            if ( con.isClosed( ) ) {
                System.out.println( "[MySQL] Connection successfully 
closed." );
            } else {
                System.err.println( "[MySQL] Can't close the mysql 
connection" );
            }
        }
    } catch ( SQLException err ) {
        System.err.println( "[MySQL] Can't close the mysql connection: " + 
err.getMessage( ) );
    }
}
//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="Update">
public void update( String query ) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( query );
        ps.executeUpdate( );
    } catch ( SQLException err ) {
        System.err.println( "[MySQL] Update error: " + err.getMessage( ) );
    }
}
//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="Query">
public ResultSet query( String query ) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( query );
        rs = ps.executeQuery( );
    } catch ( SQLException err ) {
        System.err.println( "[MySQL] Query error: " + err.getMessage( ) );
    }
    return rs;
}
//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="Getter + Setter">
public String getHostname( ) {
    return hostname;
}

public String getUsername( ) {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword( ) {
    return password;
}

public String getDatabase( ) {
    return database;
}

public int getPort( ) {
    return port;
}

public Connection getCon( ) {
    return con;
}
//</editor-fold>

}
```

pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ModuleSearcher</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuleSearcher</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.9-rc</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: No tutorials around to explain what you did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing to do with Intelij. Looks like your server is not running at localhost port 3306. Check your server is running.

Also try to use 5.1.6 connector if the server is 5.x.

Comment: I thougth because i could connect to the server by the database tab there wasn't an issue with the server. How can i check then otherwise if the server is running?

Comment: Are you able to connect using any mysql client like mysql work bench?

Comment: I just tried it and yes i was able to connect with my server throughout the mysql work bench.

Comment: What is mysql server version? 5.x? If so, did you try 5,1.6 mysql connector?<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Also check the connection string. this.con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + 
":" + port + "/" + database +
                "?autoReconnect=true", username, password );

Comment: I changed the version to 5.1.6 and it worked. Thank you very much for the help!